# Problem in RAD 7.0  with java Swing component

Tags: java

I am working on swing components and got the following error when i tried to add swing label "add(label)". Here is the error.

```
*Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00040000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 ExceptionCode=c0000005 ExceptionAddress=6918465C ContextFlags=0001003f
Handler1=008505B0 Handler2=008974F0 InaccessibleAddress=AB924D78
EDI=68D11CA4 ESI=FF333333 EAX=00000000 EBX=00000006
ECX=00000009 EDX=AB924D78
EIP=6918465C ESP=698FFC70 EBP=00000A00
Module=C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\awt.dll
Module_base_address=69170000 Offset_in_DLL=0001465c
Target=2_30_20060915_08260_lHdSMR (Windows XP 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 2)
CPU=x86 (4 logical CPUs) (0xcb53f000 RAM)
JVMDUMP006I Processing Dump Event "gpf", detail "" - Please Wait.
JVMDUMP007I JVM Requesting System Dump using 'D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\core.20110215.105747.2328.dmp'
JVMDUMP010I System Dump written to D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\core.20110215.105747.2328.dmp
JVMDUMP007I JVM Requesting Snap Dump using 'D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\Snap0001.20110215.105747.2328.trc'
JVMDUMP010I Snap Dump written to D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\Snap0001.20110215.105747.2328.trc
JVMDUMP007I JVM Requesting Java Dump using 'D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\javacore.20110215.105747.2328.txt'
JVMDUMP010I Java Dump written to D:\codeBase\Code\EncryptPassword\javacore.20110215.105747.2328.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed Dump Event "gpf", detail "".*
```

Same code is working fine in Eclipse and I can see my swing components working but giving above error in RAD 7.0. I also tried this code on another machine in RAD but got the same error. I am in serious hurry as I am getting late for my this task. All my other projects are working good in RAD 7.0.

Please tell me is this is a bug in RAD 7.0 or there is a miss in settings for JRE etc.

Thanks & Ragards

### Imran Tariq

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution.
There is a bug in RAD's default JRE.

Look at this line in error message:

Module=C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\awt.dll

After configuring another JDK, program works perfect.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. You got a Segmentation Fault, meaning, RAD tried to access to a memory that doesn't exist.